# I am not getting roots of $x^4-4x^3+3x^2+2x-30=0$

Tags: quadratics

Applying Descartes's method, I determined the interim equation as $y^4-3y^2-28=0$. Then I went on to treat this as a product of $(y^2+ky+m)(y^2-ky+n)$. Comparing coefficients of $y^2$, $y$ and constant term, I obtained $m+n-k^2=-3$, $k(n-m)=0$ and $mn=-28$. I am unable to proceed any further.

On the other hand, if I express $y^4-3y^2-28=0$ as $(y^2+7)(y^2-4)$, I get the roots as $-1$, $3$, $1+i\sqrt{7}$ and $1-i\sqrt{7}$.

Apparently, $1+i\sqrt{7}$ and $1-i\sqrt{7}$ are the correct roots. The equation seems to have two other complex roots which I am unable to find.

Appreciate any help. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Well, complex in the sense every real is complex. There are real roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
y^4-3y^2-28 = (y^2-7)(y^2 + 4)
$$
And $x=y+1$, so roots are $1\pm\sqrt7$, $1\pm 2i$.

Comment: Ah. I realize that I had reversed the sign on RHS and expressed it as $(y^2+7)(y^2-4)$. Now I get it.